# spring boot junit test + @transactional propagation required_new

Tags: spring, junit, spring-boot, transactions, spring-test

I want to test a loop that save into my DB.
I've set up a database in memory and I've loaded my scenario.
I've a basic test class named `BasicInitTest`like this

```
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = CentralApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
@Ignore
public class BasicInitTest {
.......
}
```

And all my test classes extend this and each ones have multiple `@Test` methods. In particular one of this call a `FooServiceImpl.iterateAndSave(List<FooModel>)` which iterate a list and try to save single object.

Save method are performed by `FooServiceImpl.save(Foo)` that is annotated with `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW)`. This method, before save trough `FooRepository.save(Foo)`, try to find object to throw exception or save

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW)
public Foo save(Foo foo) throws Exception {
   Foo f = fooRepository.findById(foo.getId);
   if(f) throw new Exception("ex");
   return fooRepository.saveAndFlush(foo);
}
```

Like above test still in pause on first line of service, rather, without `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW)`, it works.

I have to had annotate with `@Transactional` to prevent exception in `FooServiceImpl.iterateAndSave(List<FooModel>)` because this has a loop to iterate every single model object to perform some action and then save object.

In fact, if I remove annotation, and an save operation goes in exception, like `ConstraintViolationException`, when next object are save I get this error

```
HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.projecy.Foo entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

How can test this scenario?